# Некорректный экспорт в Word из ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic, ms-word, export, reportviewer

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой. Экспортируя отчет в Word(.doc|.docx) верхний и нижний отступ страницы пропадает. Если смотреть в предпросмотре, то там все нормально, все отступы соблюдаются. А вот в самом документе Word они рушатся. Формат документа превращается из A4 в А3.

Так я реализовал экспорт на свою кнопку:

```
Dim Bytes() As Byte = ReportPreviewForm.ReportViewer2.LocalReport.Render("WORDOPENXML", "", Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
        Dim Directory As String = "C:\"

        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Directory)) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory)
        End If

        Using Stream As New FileStream(SavePath, FileMode.Create)
            Stream.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length)
            Stream.Close()
        End Using
```

Далее идут скриншоты происходящего.

[image: Предпросмотр]
[image: В ворде]

На первой картинке изображено как это должно быть, т.е. это вариант предпросмотра в самом ReportViewer. На второй картинке вордовский документ после экспорта. Как можно заметить, в документе нету отступов сверху и снизу.
Как исправить этот баг? 3 дня мучаюсь, не могу исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос редактированием вордовского файла отдельно от экспорта

```
Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim docWord As Word.Document

    objWord = New Word.Application
    objWord.Visible = False
    docWord = objWord.Documents.Open(pathCurrent.ToString)
    docWord.Activate()
    With docWord.Application.Selection.PageSetup
        .HeaderDistance = objWord.Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
    End With
    With docWord.Application.Selection.PageSetup
        .FooterDistance = objWord.Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
    End With
    docWord.Save()
    docWord.Close()
    objWord.Quit()
    docWord = Nothing
    objWord = Nothing
```